# Is there a way to intercept all http, https traffic

Tags: http, browser, capture, traffic, intercept

I have used a lot of parent control software but none of them is perfect. I am thinking to write my own. I want to use either C++ or java or combination of two. My main issue is how to capture all traffic originating from browser.

I want to do it in a way hack proof way.

I appreciate greatly any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't intercept data transfers from your http/https connections

You will have to build a Packet sniffer and find a way to filter out the packages you are looking for, To my suprise im not getting any solid results when i try to google C++ packet sniffer tutorials, but thats defeneteley the way to go.

Comment: I know that I can use packet sniffers and first choice would be Winpcap. but I do not want to do passive listening on the line. I want to stop that packet depending on a criteria. I can do it in fiddler way but it can be bypassed by changing the settings.

Comment: That sounds more like building a firewall, i'm sorry i don't know how to help you with that.

Comment: I will find it out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For windows you need create filter driver for network adapter. Under linux you can use raw sockets for this purpose. Unfortunately, windows not support full row socket functionality.